# Value changed in NumericTextBox on 18 digit number

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have noticed that in a NumericTextBox when i add 18 or more digits in the field the numbers are changed.

For example when add the number "11111111111111111" the number is changed automatically to "11111111111111112" .

I have noticed the same behavior also in the Kendo demo web page. http://demos.kendoui.com/web/numerictextbox/index.html.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Number` is too large.

> all the positive and negative integers whose magnitude is no greater than 2^53 are representable in the Number type (indeed, the integer 0 has two representations, +0 and −0).

Read [ECMA Section 8.5 - Numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) for more information.

Comment: So you would suggest to set the length on 17 to avoid such problems ?

Comment: Actually instead of length, you should set [max](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#max-numberdefault)